# Apache2 change localhost directory on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2

After a fresh install of Ubuntu, I am trying to change the `localhost` directory of Apache2 (2.4.7). As always, it's not simple at all and it doesn't work right now.

Here's what I have done so far:

```
$sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Then in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/louisro/Documents/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

```
#DocumentRoot /var/www/html
DocumentRoot /home/louisro/Documents/www
```

in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
#DocumentRoot /var/www/html
DocumentRoot /home/louisro/Documents/www
```

Then

```
$ sudo chmod go+r /home/louisro/Documents/www
$ sudo chown -R louisro:www-data /home/louisro/Documents/www
```

When I try to access localhost throught the browser, I get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

And the log gives:

```
$ cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Fri Jan 22 09:13:38.792577 2016] [core:error] [pid 12934:tid 140432965080832] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:56772] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/louisro/Documents') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Comment: The error may also mean that directory listing is not allowed. Do you have a index.html file in your Documents/www folder ?

Comment: no I don't have an index.html file. I have the directories of all the websites I am working on.

Comment: It seems that I had to this: `$ sudo chmod 755 /home/louisro/Documents
; sudo chmod 755 /home/louisro
; sudo chmod 755 /home`

Comment: can you access https://localhost/websitename/filename ?

Comment: @louis Your document root directory probably is just missing the `x` permission for the group owner. `sudo chmod g+x /home/louisro/Documents/www` should have been enough. What you did is somewhat of a security risk, specially if you're not the only user on the system. You gave access to everyone to list the content of your home directory.

Comment: @Dan yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what solved the problem:

```
$ sudo chmod 745 /home/louisro/Documents ;
sudo chmod 745 /home/louisro ;
sudo chmod 745 /home
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `apache2.conf` to:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir enable louisro
    UserDir public_html
</IfModule>
<Directory /home/*/Documents/www>    
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All   
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Command:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /home/louisro/Documents/www
$ sudo chown -R louisro /home/louisro/Documents/www
```

remove `.htaccess` if exist and create `index.txt` file then try to access `http://localhost/index.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one essential step. After modifying the default DocumentRoot in `000-default.conf`. To take effect you should enable `000-default.conf` and restart apache2.

```
sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved as:

First, I gave permission to the directory root. In my case this directory was:

/home/paulo/Documentos/SERVER

I run the following command:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 -R /home/paulo/Documentos/SERVER
```

After, I edited the file apache2.conf with the following command:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

In the apache.conf I changed the following lines:

to

And I edited the file 000-default.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf. I changed the following lines:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html to DocumentRoot /home/paulo/Documentos/SERVER
```

Finally, I restarted the apache with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

I really hope this run in your machine;